# mongodb grouping and subgrouping with java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to query a mongodb db in such a way to get some kind of data hierarchy grouping by `field1` and `field2`. Actually from shell I can run the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{'$group': {'count': {'$sum': 1}, '_id': {'field1': '$field1', 'field2': '$field2'}}}])
```

Does anybody already did the same with java?

Comment: You can use new Document and pass parameters over there. What exactly have you tried in Java with this? What issue you are facing?

Comment: I did some like 

"AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = connection.getCollection().aggregate
    (asList(new Document("$group", new Document("_id", new Document("field1", "$filed1").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1))))));"
and it's working for grouping by field1, but I was in trouble when I want grouping by field1 and field2<br/>

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you provide sample document.

You can convert your query to `Mongo-Java` driver like following:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collectionName");

DBObject groupFieldsInId = new BasicDBObject();
groupFieldsInId.put( "field1", "$field1");
groupFieldsInId.put( "field2", "$field2");
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", groupFieldsInId);
groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(group);
```